# Align checkboxes for f.collection_check_boxes with Simple_Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, simple-form

I am using RoR and I am using the Simple_Form gem for my forms.  I have an object relation whereby a User can have multiple Roles, and during creation, the admin can select which Roles to apply to the new User.  I would like the Roles to have their checkbox on the left, and their name on the right in a horizontal arrangement.

//
"box" Admin 
//

instead of the current

//

"box"

Admin

//

My current code to show the Roles is this.

```
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label 'Roles' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes 
                 :role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The part I am most getting hung up on is the fact that the f.collection_check_boxes generates code like this.

```
<span>
  <input blah blah />
  <label class="collection_check_boxes" blah>blah</label>
</span>
```

Which makes it hard for me to get a css class in there as there are 3 components that have to be touched.  I've tried adding things such as dummy classes to the :html hash, but the dummy class doesn't even show up in the rendered html.

Any help is greatly appreciated

**EDIT: Solution**

Thanks to Baldrick, my working erb looks like this.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name,
      {:item_wrapper_class => 'checkbox_container'} %>
```

And my CSS is as follows

```
.checkbox_container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: -1px;
  margin: 5px;
 }
.checkbox_container input {
  display: inline;
 }
.checkbox_container .collection_check_boxes{
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: -5px;
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [doc of collection_check_boxes](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/ActionViewExtensions/Builder#collection_check_boxes-instance_method), there is an option `item_wrapper_class` to give a css class to the span containing the checkbox. Use it like that

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name, :item_wrapper_class => 'checkbox_container' %>
```

And a CSS style to keep the checkbox and the label on the same line:

```
.checkbox_container input {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty much the answer.

Comment: I guess things have changed (again), as no span is created with "collection_check_boxes, the page linked does not have "item_wrapper_class" anywhere on it, and nothing changes in the resulting page html if you put this in.   I added a class to the surrounding div, then used css ">" to affect the elements within it.

Answer (score 5):

In the latest 2.1.0 branch of SimpleForm with 2.3.1.0 of bootstrap-saas, installed with bootstrap option, the collection_check_boxes method resulted in some spans to which applying the inline item wrapper class had no good effect.

I was able to get the form to line up perfectly using the standard input, collection, :as => :check_boxes methodology.  Then the inline style worked perfectly:

```
<%= f.input :roles, :collection => valid_roles, :label_method => :last, :value_method => :first, :as => :check_boxes, :item_wrapper_class => 'inline'  %>
```

My roles happen to be a simple array of arrays with value, label.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

This was the first SO page for a DDG search with 'rails collection_check_boxes bootstrap', but it's not about Bootstrap, but here is a solution for Bootstrap 4 anyways.

This works with plain Rails and Bootstrap 4, no gem required. [`collection_check_boxes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) is a plain Rails method.

```
  .form-group
    =f.label :industry_interest
    %br
    =f.collection_check_boxes :industry_interest, Industry.all, :id, :name do |cb|
      =cb.check_box 
      =cb.label
      %br
```

or

```
  .form-group
    =f.label :industry_interest
    =f.collection_check_boxes :industry_interest, Industry.all, :id, :name do |cb|
      .form-check
        =cb.label class: 'form-check-label' do
          =cb.check_box class: 'form-check-input'
          =cb.text
```

They look identical.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios

Comment: Adding a `%br` element in the end will give all boxes with labels in different lines as well. Otherwise I got them all in one row.

Answer (score 3):

With Bootstrap you can:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name, :item_wrapper_class => 'inline' %>
```