# Align Checkbox and Label with collection_check_box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the same problem as the poster here [Align checkboxes for f.collection_check_boxes with Simple_Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146023/align-checkboxes-for-f-collection-check-boxes-with-simple-form)

My checkbox code is:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :investor_city_ids, r.cities, :id, :name, {:item_wrapper_class => 'checkbox_container'} %>
```

But I see in the HTML generated that the class is not being set for the HTML generated

```
<input id="investor_investor_city_ids_1" name="investor[investor_city_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<label for="investor_investor_city_ids_1">Hamilton</label>
<input id="investor_investor_city_ids_2" name="investor[investor_city_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2">
<label for="investor_investor_city_ids_2">Cambridge</label>
```

I've tried the collection_check_boxes code without the {} braces also but nothing seems to have any effect.

CSS is

```
.checkbox_container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: -1px;
  margin: 5px;
 }
.checkbox_container input {
  display: inline;
 }
.checkbox_container .collection_check_boxes{
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: -5px;
 }
```

Comment: Got any CSS for us to see?

Comment: added. My question is that the class is not being included in the generated HTML.

Comment: Do you happen to be using Zurb's Foundation?

Comment: If you could setup this in say a jsbin or link to a live version, I can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed - I was using form_for, changing to simple_form_for resolved this. Not sure why it wasn't working for form_for.

Comment: Because `form_for` uses another API, and doesn't create a wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder%3acollection_check_boxes). You need to specify the item_wrapper_tag for the class to be added. You could also use collection_wrapper_tag + class.

Let us know if it works.

GL & HF

Comment: Thanks for replying. I changed the collection to

<%= f.collection_check_boxes :city_ids, r.cities, :id, :name, {:collection_wrapper_tag => 'ul', :item_wrapper_tag => 'li', :item_wrapper_class => 'checkbox_container'} %>

However the HTML is still not rendering with the classes or tags applied. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?