# How to align input and label from collection_check_boxes?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using `collection_check_boxes` and have problems with aligning checkbox and text. This is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :dog_ids, Dog.all, :id, :name %>
</div>
```

Form is displayed like this:

```
[checkbox1]
  text1

[checkbox2]
  text2

[checkbox3]
  text3
```

I am trying to align input and label but didn't have success. I have seen these question but it don't work for me: [Align checkboxes for f.collection_check_boxes with Simple_Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146023/align-checkboxes-for-f-collection-check-boxes-with-simple-form)

I want to accomplish this:

```
[checkbox1] text1

[checkbox2] text2

[checkbox3] text3
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: <div class="row"><div class="col-xs-4">[checkbox1]</div><div class="col-xs-8">text1</div></div>

Comment: @Octopus-Paul, thank you but how to apply that to collection_check_boxes?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The definition for `collection_check_boxes`:

```
collection_check_boxes(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

The last argument permits you to do something like this: (this does exactly what you want using collection_check_boxes)

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:dog_ids, Dog.all, :id, :name) do |b| %>
  <div class="row">
    <%= b.label(class: "check_box") do %>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <%= b.check_box(class: "check_box") %>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <%= b.object.name %>
      </div>       
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Read more about [collection_check_boxes](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)

There is another method too: style your checkbox input and your label from css.

For a better css specificity I will add a new class named 'checkbox-list' to:

```
<div class="col-md-4 checkbox-list">
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :dog_ids, Dog.all, :id, :name %>
</div>

.checkbox-list input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
}

.checkbox-list input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks great for me. The only thing is, I don't know why does it say this: `unexpected ',', expecting ')'` for this part: `:dog_ids, Dog.all`

Comment: Try now please. I made a small change