# Best way to access a value from a database with Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating an educaional managemnet system that allows you to keep track of students, classes, departments, sections, professors, and semesters using ruby on rails. Every table except sections_student was created using rails g scaffold. Here is my current ERD.
[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkkBO.png)

I'm trying to edit the _form.html.erb for students to display checkboxes so the student can add classes. I have it set up and it shows there are courses but they don't show the course number. I believe it is showing the address of the course object [Student _form.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDAq9.png)

This is the piece of code I'm using to show the checkboxes. I tried changing :course to :course.number but it says "undefined method `number' for :course:Symbol". :

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :section_id %>
  <%= form.collection_check_boxes(:section_ids, @sections, :id, :course) %>
</div>
```

I'm confused because in students/show.html.erb I'm able to display the course number easily with section.course.number here:

```
<ol>
 <% @student.sections.each do |section| %>
  <li><%=section.course.number%> Credit Hours: <%=section.course.hours%> <%=section.professor.name %> 
  </li>
 <% end %>
</ol>
```

Here is what it looks like [Working course display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9qc0.png)

If you need any more information please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Its throwing an error here: `<%=section.course.number%>` - what does `section.course` return? It looks like a symbol `:course`, rather than an instance of a Course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now `collection_check_boxes` is calling `.course` on every section. You probably want to call `course.number`. One way to achieve this would be to add something like

```
def course_number
  course.number
end
```

to your `Section`-Model, and then use it:

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes(:section_ids, @sections, :id, :course_number) %>
```

Comment: Incredible! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just curious, what other ways would you be able to achieve this?

Comment: `collection_check_boxes` is a very high level helper, and if it doesn't suit your needs you might simply want to iterate through the collection yourself and use https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box for building the individual checkboxes and manually add a label.

Comment: Actually `collection_check_boxes` accepts a block - maybe the first answer here would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109276/how-to-align-input-and-label-from-collection-check-boxes