# How to append html in collection_check_boxes (Rails 4)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to loop through a record and generate html code that will create a list of checklists like this:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:user_ids, User.all, :id, :fullname) do |cb| %>
  <% cb.label do %>
    <%= cb.check_box + cb.text %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This code generates cheklist items as expected without a break in between. But when I try to add a `</br>` tag after each label like:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:user_ids, User.all, :id, :fullname) do |cb| %>
  <% cb.label do %>
    <%= cb.check_box + cb.text %>
  <% end %>
</br>
<% end %>
```

The labels do not appear in the generated HTML and I only get the `</br>` tags. Is there a way to append the html code in another way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason you get only `<br />` tag is that the helper f.collection_check_boxes returns the last element inside the block, you can try this:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:user_ids, User.all, :id, :fullname) do |cb| %>
  <% cb.label do %>
    <%= cb.check_box + cb.text %><br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

or you set a list like that

```
<ul>
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:user_ids, User.all, :id, :fullname) do |cb| %>
  <% cb.label do %>
    <li><%= cb.check_box + cb.text %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Abdoo - the second approach (using lists works). The first one doesn't work since the break ends up within the <label> tag.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5, this is working (note <%**=** cb.label do %>):

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:user_ids, User.all, :id, :fullname) do |cb| %>
  <%= cb.label do %>
    <%= cb.check_box + cb.text %>
  <% end %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to append html code to a form is with the `input_html` option:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:user_ids, User.all, :id, :fullname), input_html: { style: "margin-bottom: 20px" } do |cb| %>
  <% cb.label do %>
    <%= cb.check_box + cb.text %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or use `item_wrapper_class` in a similar fashion as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146023/align-checkboxes-for-f-collection-check-boxes-with-simple-form).